# how to keep sockets sending data in setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am trying to send data to a node server with socket.io. I have the connection working perfectly but the data is not coming over like I want. Currently in my webpage I have a canvas set up with webGl and within this webGl I spawn balls on the canvas using the setInterval method. I have an array that holds this list of balls and I want to be able to track the position of every ball until they go off screen. Currently now all I am getting is the first position of every ball being sent to the server but I think its due to my placement of the socket. But when I move the socket code I loose reference to the balls position.

I set the timer and variables like this:

```
var ballArray =[];
var i = 0;
//The timer for creating the balls at a set interval
var timer = setInterval(function() { addBall() }, 600);
```

So the tiumer is set for 600 milliseconds and calls the addBall() function.

```
    //Checks to make sure there is a set amount of balls and does not grow too large
    function addBall()
        {
            if(i <= 10)
            {
                createBall();
                scene.add(ballArray[i]);
                i++;
                console.log(i);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Finished");
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
```

If there is over 11 balls on screen the tiomer will stop if not it waill spawn a new ball in the createBall() function:

```
function createBall()
        {
            //create the ball object with physics
            ball = new Physijs.SphereMesh(
            new THREE.SphereGeometry(Math.random() * (4 - 1) + 1,16,16),
            Physijs.createMaterial(new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial(
            {
                color: 0xff0000,
                reflectivity: 0.8
            }),0.4,0.6),1 );
            //Positioning data
            var r = 
            {
                x: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12,
                y: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12,
                z: Math.random() * (Math.PI - Math.PI / 12) + Math.PI / 12
            };

            //Setting the pos of the ball
            ball.rotation.set(r.x, r.y, r.z);
            ball.position.y = 40;
            ball.castShadow = true;
            ball.receiveShadow = true;
            ballArray[i] = ball;
            //sending the data of the ball to the sever
            socket.emit('Ball',  { name : "ballArray"+i, X : ballArray[i].position.x, Y : ballArray[i].position.y, Z : ballArray[i].position.z});
        }
```

Here then all the conditions for the ball are set and the ball will spawn and then I set my socket to send the info.
I think because I call it on the set interval the socket sends once then sends again for the next ball instead of sending data constantly for all the balls. I know I could use an array to have a set amount of balls but I want to be able to in time take out the limit on the ball count.
Is there a way around this or will I have to re-code this part to better implement what I am trying to do?
Any guidancxe would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to transmit the data periodically in your update function not in your `createBall` function. So in your update function that is called every frame you would loop over the array and for every existing ball transmit the data.

It would be better to batch all balls into a single package and to not do it *every* frame but I guess these are performance related things you're probably not worrying about yet.